# Imprimir nodes selecionados de uma JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Tenho esta JTree:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho este código que me retorna todos os nodes da `JTree`:

```
public void print() {
        recurse((TreeNode) jTree2.getModel().getRoot());
    }

    public void recurse(TreeNode theNode) {
        System.out.println("1-- " + theNode);
        for (Enumeration theChildren = theNode.children(); theChildren.hasMoreElements();) {
            recurse((TreeNode) theChildren.nextElement());
        }
    }
```

**Output desse código:**

```
1-- JTree
1-- colors
1-- blue
1-- violet
1-- red
1-- yellow
```

Há alguma forma de adaptar esse código de impressão da jTree mas só com os nodes selecionados?

O código seguinte retorna um Objects com os caminhos:

```
TreePath[] checkedPaths = checkTreeManager.getSelectionModel().getSelectionPaths();
         for (TreePath s : checkedPaths) {
         System.out.println(s);
            }
         }
```

No caso da JTree que postei o output do código anterior é:

```
[JTree, colors, blue]
[JTree, colors, violet]
```

Comment: Txii recursividade não é fácil ;) sabes se um node está selecionado ou não? Isto é esse código sabes? se sim publica o código como o fazes... (é que eu não faço a mínima nunca usei essas jtree)

Comment: Vou colocar o código na pergunta !

Comment: ja me ocorreram algumas formas de resolver isso, mas acho que são todas elas chamando pelo nome "GAMBIARRAS" ;) por exemplo uma delas, metes esse ultimo código numa função em que entra como parametro esse node da função recursiva, `verificaIsSelecionado(TreeNode nome)` e depois verificas se esses node existe dentro do `checkedPaths` se sim imprimes se não, não imprimes... Como disse é uma solução meio Gambiarra mas nao conheço nenhuma melhor

Comment: A questão é como é que eu depois vou buscar o node ao checkedPaths se o que ele retorna é um objeto por exemplo:[JTree, colors, blue]. Se eu fizer um verificaIsSelecionado(blue); como é que vou percorrer o Path [JTree, colors, blue] ?

Comment: pois não tinha pensado nisso, mas tens de ter um método qualquer que te devolve o node, isto porque ele sabe o caminho até ele logo também te pode devolver. (digo eu)

Comment: [JTree, colors, blue] isso é um Object porque eu tentei aquela cena que me ensinaste: for (TreePath s : checkedPaths) {
         if(s instanceof Object) System.out.println("Entrei");
            } E ele assume como sendo um objeto, há maneira de eu percorrer esse objeto ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19428/discussion-between-jsantos1991-and-hugo-machado).